# Error while trying to read n images using a loop?

Tags: c

```
void main() {
int frame_number = 0;
do {
    char *filename = "";
    strcpy(filename, "frame_");
    char *frame_id = "";
    itoa(frame_number, frame_id, 10);
    strcat(filename, frame_id);
    strcat(filename, ".bmp");

    FILE* f  = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!f) {
        printf("Could not read!");
        system("Pause");
    }
    else
        printf("Read!");
    fclose(f);
    frame_number++;
} while (frame_number < 20);
}
```

Whenever I run this I get the error of `access violation writing location` !!!
There are around 40 images in the folder.
How to solve this ?

Comment: There are *thousands* of duplicates of this on this website. Please take a moment to search it.

Answer (score 1):

No memory has been allocated for `filename` and `frame_id`. Allocate memory before storing strings using [malloc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) or [calloc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html). Or just declare them as static arrays.

```
char filename[256]="";
char frame_id[256] = "";
```